# Local site on IIS has slow performance using Chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, iis, localhost, blocking

When I browse to a local site on IIS using Chrome I get intermittent slow performance.

It doesn't seem to matter whether the request is a full page request or an ajax request, it happens a significant percentage of the time, enough to slow down my development or make me use a different browser. Browsing to the same site in the live environment runs fine. Firefox and IE are running fine, just seems to be Chrome.

The network tab is showing the delay on the Blocking phase on my machine so I don't think it's a problem with DNS and disabling IPv6 didn't help me. Could it be something to do with the application or session cookies? I'm running Windows 8.1 with IIS 8.5 and the general performance of the machine is good.

Very frustrating because I prefer Chrome tools to the dev tools in other browsers and I've not had this issue on other dev machines where I've used Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all your data (cookies, history and cache) if that doesn't work, reboot your PC, if that doesn't work, reinstall Chrome.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that I'm afraid. Also deleted the default Chrome profile so that it was regenerated in case it was something to do with that. Even a clean install of Chrome hasn't changed anything!

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything else

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help. Shame but I'm just going to stop using Chrome. I'm happy at least that it's not an issue with the site and with Chrome on my dev box.

Comment: This is a real shame that 2 years later, and from 2 years prior to this article, this issue continues!  I love chrome browser, and developing with chrome browser, but this is KILLING ME!  Its still so slow.